# Telegram Bot - конвертер видео в видеокружки

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую функцию у бота в телеграме: пользователь присылает боту видео в , а бот в ответ должен прислать видео-кружок из этого видео.
Использую aiogram, но и на другой библиотеке пойму

Comment: Вам нужно сделать обработку видео в нужный вид, боты тут ни причем. Кст, а как такое выглядит? Добавьте пример в вопрос (кнопка `править`), например в виде картинки: до и после

Comment: https://telegram.org/blog/video-messages-and-telescope#meet-telescope